# FOSUserBundle Do I copy the action code into my own actions

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm having some issues working with FOSUserBundle. I find the documentation lacking and think it would really help if they had an example application that I could download the source code for and look at.

My login route is `/Login`. I've overrode the twig template so that I get a login form displaying when I navigate to my route. However I had to add some default values into my LoginAction to make it work.

My LoginAction:

```
/**
     * @Route("/Login", name="wx_exchange_login")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig")
     * User log up - Open to public
     * Authenticates users to the system
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return array('error' => 0, 'csrf_token' => 'foobar', 'last_username' => 'foobar');
    }
```

FOSUserBundle [LoginAction](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L20)

I was under the impression that since FOSUserBundle had the Action code already defined I wouldn't need to have any code in my loginAction. It's not clear from the docs that I am supposed to do anything in my action. I've seen some examples online showing people having copied the code from relevant FOSUserBundle action into their own action.

Is the correct way to implement FOSUserBundle to copy their code into your own actions?

**Edit:** I am not overriding the bundle.

**Edit 2:** My routing.yml is slightly different from the docs. My first entry is:

```
wx_exchange:
    resource: "@WXExchangeBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

The remaining entries are as stated in the docs (importing the FOSUserBundle routes).

Security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /Login
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/Login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/SignUp, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ResetPassword, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/Confirm, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/Dashboard/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: You sure you read this all through? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md Seems pretty clear to me. Which version of the bundle are you using? 1.2, 1.3 or latest? If you really can't get out, I'll help you ASAP :) Btw, how does your app/config/security.yml file looks like?

Comment: I'm using the master version and I've completed the steps on the first page. According to the text after completing those steps I should now be able to login at http://app.com/app_dev.php/login, but I did not find this to be the case.

Comment: What are the contents of your security.yml file? Would like to see this if everything looks right :) Thanks!

Comment: @Wcool Just posted it.

Comment: What's the error you get? In my login form I need underscores. See my code: Form `<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method='post' class='form-validate' id="test">` CSRF input `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />` Password `<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required">` Submit btn `<input type="submit" name="_submit"`.

Comment: I was getting errors that the variable `error`, `csrf_token` and `last_username` were not defined when my loginAction was only returning an empty array. So I put in those defaults. It's not clear from the documentation that you have to do anything in your action. I thought that since the bundle came with the predefined actions you wouldn't need to do anything in your own action. I'm confused if the code is already there why do I have to put more code in mine. As for the twig code I'm extending the one from FOS and it's working fine. Just the action is causing me issues.

Comment: I will look into this more, just need some time :(. In the meantime, here is a list of all defaults of security.yml. Maybe a FOS expert might also be interested in this, it does indeed gives me headaches too. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html edit: You sure you specified the `name` fields of your form correctly? You MIGHT (not sure) need a $form->isValid() if statement too.

Comment: What happens if you 'copy / paste' the code of the FOS login action? I have a project here too with FOSUserBundle, just need to find some time as it's been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have finally got an answer to this. The code for the login part is indeed already defined in the FOSUserBundle. I looked at the routing of my own project and can see that it looks like this:

```
fos_user_security_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

//Check a login:
fos_user_security_check:
    pattern: /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
    methods: [POST]

//The logout route:
fos_user_security_logout:
    pattern: /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

Now, these routes all point to the SecurityController of the bundle with those methods in it. This class can be found in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php and the routing can be found in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml (I converted it in this post to YAML for easier understanding).

So, the only thing you need to do is do a reference (import) in the routing file in the app folder to this security.yml file.

To answer your question: I don't think you need to define these in your own controller as they're already defined in the above mentioned files.

If I can find more details I'll post them ASAP. Been a while that I used this bundle. I now use the builtin Symfony2 elements, which I find more transparent in the long run.

**Edit:** In the routing file of my own bundle I have the references to those XML files:

```
// FOSUser files
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: user/profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: user/register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: user/resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: user/profile
```

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly what I had except I have `workout_exchange_wx_exchange:
    resource: "@WXExchangeBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /`
My login route is defined in the controller as an annotation to be 
`/**
     * @Route("/Login", name="wx_exchange_login")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig")
  * User login - Open to public
  * Authenticates users to the system
     */`
If I remove that route I get a 404 error. I'm wondering if FOSUserBundle can work with annotated routes. I think I'll head over to the Github site and ask them. Thanks so much.

Comment: The routes are in files distributed with the bundle, you don't need to write your own actions for login / logout / register etc. That's the point I was trying to make anyway :) Glad it helped you sort of

Comment: I haven't read your comment closely enough. I think that the bundle indeed does not support annotation routing the way you'd like :) Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the effort you've put in. I've abandoned FOSUserBundle for now and managed to get login/registration working using the Symfony docs.